# How to truncate sys.conversation_endpoints

Tags: sql, sql-server, truncate, service-broker

We use service brokers more than two months and suddenly I found that the overall performance of the system is decreased. After digging a lot and analyzing metrics, I found that my `page life expectancy` is very low. then I take a look at my buffer pool with the help of [simplesqlserver](https://simplesqlserver.com/2014/01/08/cleaning-up-the-buffer-pool/), it fills with sys.sysdercv object (5 GB). after searching a bit more I found that the `sys.conversation_endpoint` has 19 million rows with **10 GB data**. it was my mistake to not end conversation in target queue but after ending conversation in both side (the initiator and the target queue) it still remains in the `sys.conversation_endpoints` with CD state (Closed). one way to delete this rows is to call `end conversation with cleanup` but it takes a lot of time to complete. I write this job but I guess it takes more than 7 days to be completed. here is my job:

```
DECLARE @BatchSize Int 

SELECT @BatchSize = 1000

declare @i int = @BatchSize;
declare @sum int = 0;
WHILE @i = @BatchSize BEGIN
    print concat('while ', @sum);

    select @i = 0;
    declare @handle uniqueidentifier
    declare conv cursor for select top (@BatchSize) conversation_handle from sys.conversation_endpoints
    open conv
    fetch NEXT FROM conv into @handle
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        select @i = @i + 1;
        END Conversation @handle with cleanup
        fetch NEXT FROM conv into @handle
    End
    close conv
    deallocate conv 
    select @sum = @sum + @i;
END
```

so, here is my question: How can I truncate this table and its data all at once. just like truncate command `truncate table sys.conversation_endpoints`, this command generate this error:

```
Cannot find the object "conversation_endpoints" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

I want to know, Is there any service to restart it or do any thing that safely remove this huge amount of data?

Comment: If you want to clear all conversations and messages, schedule a maintenance window and `ALTER  DATABASE...NEW_BROKER`. Don't forget to fix the root cause of the problem (my guess is the [fire-and-forget](https://rusanu.com/2006/04/06/fire-and-forget-good-for-the-military-but-not-for-service-broker-conversations/) anti-pattern).

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanGuzman. it saves my day. I changed my queue and its activation sp in the correct way but there is conversation_endpoint rows with CD state. why it remains with Closed state.

Comment: Most likely the [lifetime](https://rusanu.com/2014/03/31/how-to-prevent-conversation-endpoint-leaks/) has not yet expired, which is 30 minutes by default.